# Qt multi-threaded display synchronization problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

We developed an image processing and display program based on Qt. We use sub-threads for image processing and the main thread as UI display. In order to display synchronization, we use the Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection parameter when connecting the signal-slot. There are other threads that may overwrite the image data, so we use locks.
code show as below:

```
class ProcessThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ProcessThread(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void run() override
    {
        int i=0;
        while (1)
        {
            if(isQuit)break;

            mutex.lock();

            QString filename=QString("/home/%1.bmp").arg((i++)%2000);
            data=imread(filename.toStdString());

            //dosomthing...

            emit processCompleted(&data);

            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

    void setIsQuit(bool v){isQuit=v;}

signals:
    void processCompleted(const Mat *data);

private:
    bool isQuit=false;
    Mat data;
    QMutex mutex;
};
```

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr): QWidget(parent)
    {
        thread=new ProcessThread();

        connect(thread,SIGNAL(processCompleted(const Mat *)),
                this,SLOT(processCompleted(const Mat *)),Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);

        thread->start();
    }

    ~Widget()
    {
        thread->setIsQuit(true);

        thread->quit();
        thread->wait();
        delete thread;
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event)
        QPainter p(this);
        p.drawImage(QPoint(0,0),image);
    }

private slots:
    void processCompleted(const Mat *data)
    {
        if(data!=nullptr)
        {
            if(data->channels()==1)
            {
                image=QImage(data->data,
                             data->cols,
                             data->rows,
                             data->step,
                             QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
            }
            else
            {
                image=QImage(data->data,
                             data->cols,
                             data->rows,
                             data->step,
                             QImage::Format_RGB888);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            image=QImage();
        }

        repaint();
    }

private:
    QImage image;
    ProcessThread *thread;
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

1. When I exit the program, it will be stuck in thread->wait() in the ~Widget() function; it cannot continue to execute;
2. If I comment out thread->wait(); it will not get stuck when exiting, but it will prompt: "QMutex: destroying locked mutex" and "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running" errors;
3. If the Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection parameter is not used when connecting the signal-slot, the first problem above will not occur, but the display will not be synchronized.

We need to display synchronization, how can we do that? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to synchronize the access to `ProcessThread::isQuit` too... otherwise you cannot be sure that the thread will read it correctly. Then dont use the `quit()` method but let the thread to terminate naturally with `isQuit` check

Comment: Why do you use `BlockingQueuedConnection`? Whenever I do work like this, the default (QueuedConnection) works just fine. For your application I would recommend to use QtConcurrent framework instead of setting up worker threads manually.

Comment: If BlockingQueuedConnection is not used, the processing thread will not be synchronized with the UI main thread, that is, the processing thread will not wait for the display refresh of the UI main thread, which will cause display confusion.

Comment: I put the image processing thread in the QtConcurrent framework, but it still deadlocks when wairForFinished().

Comment: The use of a mutex in the code shown is incomplete/redundant: there's really no point if the mutex is used by only one thread.  You also use the [`QImage` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#QImage-5) that reuses the `Mat` data pointer without making a deep copy, so you have multiple threads potentially accessing the same memory locations without any synchronization -- that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: In addition to the processing thread and UI thread, Mat *data will be used by other threads, so I added a mutex. I didn't put the other thread code out for simplicity.